# QuickContactBadge overlay

Tags: android, quickcontactbadge

I am using a QuickContactBadge in my app and it works nicely.

However, the badge shows a small overlay in the bottom right corner. I suppose it's there to indicate that it is a `QuickContactBadge` and not just a picture. I am totally fine with this, however, since I am using `Holo.Light` in my app, the contact badge shows a *dark* overlay. In, for example, the stock dialer with `Holo.Dark`, the overlay is light.

I understand the reasoning for this, however the dark overlay is just ugly on top of most contact photos, whereas the light overlay works for most.

So, how could I override the overlay, and force the badge to show the light (i.e. the one for `Holo.Dark`) overlay?

Looking at the Android source for `QuickContactBadge`, the `Drawable` for the overlay, `mOverlay`, is private and thus not directly accessible from my app. The `Drawable` is set in the constructor:

```
public QuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray styledAttributes = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);
    mOverlay = styledAttributes.getDrawable(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.Theme_quickContactBadgeOverlay);
    styledAttributes.recycle();

    mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(mContext.getContentResolver());
    setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I assume I have to extend the entire `QuickContactBadge` class to solve this, but I'm fairly new to both Android and Java so I have no idea on how to do that. I've extended `ListAdapter`s before, but when I try to extend this badge I run into the problem of having to access internal Android resources, which I can't.

The other solution I can think of is to "trick" the badge that I'm using `Holo.Dark` but I have no idea how to do that.

Has anyone done anything similar or can at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with ImageView instead of QuickContactBadge

Comment: How do I get access to the contact badge using an ImageView?

Comment: I eventually went with this route. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In SDK 21 Google added a `setOverlay(Drawable drawable)` method.

It accepts null, so another option to hide the decorator and keep the QuickContactBadge functionality is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    contactBadge.setOverlay(null);
}
```